# C++ struct constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

I tried to create my own structure. So I wrote this piece of code.

```
struct node
{
    int val, id;
    node(int init_val, int init_id)
    {
        val = init_val;
        id = init_id;
    }
};

node t[100];

int main()
{
...
}
```

I tried to compile my program. But I got an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'node::node()'
note: candidates are:
note: node::node(int, int)
note: candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
note: node::node(const node&)
note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: `node t[100];` default-constructs each element, but `node` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a type require a default constructor in order to declare an array of it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231414/does-a-type-require-a-default-constructor-in-order-to-declare-an-array-of-it)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
node t[100];
```

will try to initialise the array by calling a default constructor for `node`.  You could either provide a default constructor

```
node()
{
    val = 0;
    id = 0;
}
```

or, rather verbosely, initialise all 100 elements explicitly

```
node t[100] = {{0,0}, {2,5}, ...}; // repeat for 100 elements
```

or, since you're using C++, use `std::vector` instead, appending to it (using `push_back`) at runtime

```
std::vector<node> t;
```

Answer (score 11):

This will fix your error.

```
struct node
{
int val, id;
node(){};

node(int init_val, int init_id)
{
    val = init_val;
    id = init_id;
}
};
```

You should declare default constructor.