# Error in calling constructor

Tags: c++, class, struct, constructor

I tried to call a structure's constructor from a class constructor but its throwing an error. I have been trying to solve this for 30 mins

**Structure:**

```
struct node
{
    int val;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node(int x)
    {
        val = x;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }

    ~node()
    {
        delete(left);
        delete(right);
    }
};
```

**class:**

```
class Tree
{
    node* head;
    node list[1000];
    bool flag[1000] = {0};
public:
    Tree(int x)
    {
        head = new node(x);
    }
```

**main() method:**

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {50,35,75,20,45,60,90,10,25,40,47,65,80,120,1,15,23,30,39,
46,49,82,110,21,24,48};
    Tree t(a[0]);
```

the error I am getting is

**Error Log:**

```
In constructor 'Tree::Tree(int)':|
|37|error: no matching function for call to 'node::node()'|
|37|note: candidates are:|
|17|note: node::node(int)|
|17|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
|12|note: node::node(const node&)|
|12|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
```

the structure constructor has one argument and in the class constructor I am calling with one argument yet the the error is throwing that the program call with 0 argument. I don't know where the problem is.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a default constructor.

The same Question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743115/c-struct-constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
node list[1000];
```

is an array of structures. A structure being element of the array needs a default constructor (or initializer has to be explicitly specified, [see example](http://ideone.com/mO0vFk)), thus the error. Add a default constructor to `node`.

---

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 12.6.1/3

> [ Note: If T is a class type with no default constructor, any
>   declaration of an object of type T (or array thereof) is ill-formed if
>   no initializer is explicitly specified (see 12.6 and 8.5). — end note
>   ]

Comment: Or better yet use an std::vector

Comment: Alternative: Use an initializer array.

Comment: Or remove the array completely. What is it even doing there? Providing preallocated nodes for the tree? Then why allocate a node dynamically in the constructor?

Comment: sure, there are many alternatives, I just give the answer to the problem. I answer what is the problem

Comment: Thanks. I want the array to keep the path as traversing through tree. now I changed it to array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The `Tree` class contains nodes:

```
node list[1000];
```

which need to be default-initialised. But there's no default constructor to do that with.

Assuming you actually want a thousand nodes separate from the ones that make up the tree, You could make your existing constructor usable as a default constructor by giving it a default argument:

```
node(int x = 0)
```

or add a separate default constructor, for example:

```
node() : val(0), left(0), right(0) {}
```

or you might avoid the need for a default constructor by replacing the array with a more friendly container

```
std::vector<node> list;
```

and initialise that to the size you want in the constructor:

```
Tree(int x) : head(new node(x)), list(1000, node(0)) {}
```